# How to get the path to image stored in content folder .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using this code to get an image from the Content/img folder in visual studio:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(@"~\Content\img\toendra.JPG");
```

This gives me the error that the file is not found. However if I give the absolute path to the image, it works:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Stijn\Source\Repos\groep11DotNet\p2groep11.Net\Content\img\toendra.JPG");
```

What is wrong with my relative path?

Comment: Which folder that your program executes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.Drawing.Image.FromFile` doesn't know how to handle an ASP.NET application root relative path. So you have to use an intermediate function to convert it to a physical file path that it can understand.

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/toendra.JPG"));
```

Notice I converted your backslashes to forward slashes (which are the correct symbols to use in a URL) and that eliminated the need for the string literal.

If you're going to use it a lot, might make a helper utility class.

```
public static class ImageHelper
{
    public static Image LoadFromAspNetUrl(string url)
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Can't use HttpContext.Current in non-ASP.NET context");
        }
        return Image.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(url));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Image myImage = ImageHelper.LoadFromAspNetUrl("~/Content/img/toendra.JPG");
```

Comment: I tried this but then I get "Cannot resolve symbol" on Server.MapPath, there isn't an option to import it

Comment: @HardUser See updated answer. If you're in certain locations in ASP.NET then `Server` is a property of the inherited class, so you can use it directly. But if you're somewhere outside that context, then you can use `HttpContext.Current.Server` to access the `HttpServerUtility`.