# how to run a notification sound (bell) in website in the if condition in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to ring a bell in a website if the string value = "UP". I have tried to console. beeps (), its working in local machine but not in remote as its a website. how to ring a bell in web applications.

```
                   if  (status !="DN")
                    {
                    Console.Beep(5000, 1000);
                    }
```

Comment: play sound on server or client browser, what is this mvc or simple asp?

Comment: client browser. i mean user uses website.in the website it should give alert

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to play a sound in asp.net web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329191/how-to-play-a-sound-in-asp-net-web-page)

Comment: i used this but not working . what should i change if i have a sound file in sounds folder . Response.Write("<embed height='0' width='0' src='sound1.wav' />");

Comment: I'm imagining a dev server in a datacenter somewhere beeping wildly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<object>` or  `<embed>` html tags and make these as server control, `runat="server"` and give them Ids.

```
<object id="audiofile" runat="server" data=""></object>
Or HTML5 tag

<audio id ="audioTag" runat="server" src="">
  <p>This browser does not support audio.</p>
</audio>
```

In code behind [check browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx) and set the src to audio tag if its html5 supportive else to object

```
     if  (status !="DN")
                        {
         if(!html5browser)
                        audiofile.attributes.add("data","path/audiofile");
        else
                   audiotag.attributes.add("src","path/audiofile");
                        }
```

**Using Response.write**

```
Response.Write("<embed height='0' width='0' src='path/audiodile' />");
```

Comment: in your answer, what do u mean by path , in my case what will be the path.my file location is "D:\..\..\..\applicationName\sounds"

Comment: resource path: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx and this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080367/how-to-get-the-path-to-image-stored-in-content-folder-net